# How to find size of a file before downloading it in iOS 7?

Tags: iphone, ios7, nsurlconnection

Wanted to find size of a file on some server before downloading it in iOS 7... I have a method of NSURLConnectionDelegate but it is deprecated after iOS 4.3

Here was that method:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
```

Comment: Check this Swift 4 solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48584914/3161503

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should instead use the [`NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) *Note*: DATADelegate

and its `didReceiveResponse:` method to send a [HEAD request](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_methods.htm) to get just the header:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response;
```

Then you can get the response size with @Port's suggestion:

```
long long size = [response expectedContentLength];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, was very helpful!! :)
NSURLCONNECTIONDELEGATE has many methods deprecated, these are now presented in NSURLCONNECTIONDATADELEGATE!

Answer (score 10):

Make a request using the HEAD method. For example:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];
```

This request will be identical to a GET but it won't return the body. Then call

```
long long size = [response expectedContentLength];
```

Complete example with NSURLConnection (works for NSURLSession too of course):

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];
NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error: nil];
long long size = [response expectedContentLength];
NSLog(@"%lld",size);
```

This is also useful to conditionally download based on the Last-Modified header (assuming that the server sends you that).

```
if ([response respondsToSelector:@selector(allHeaderFields)]) {
    NSString *lastModifiedString = [[response allHeaderFields] objectForKey:@"Last-Modified"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this method,NSURLResponse object which is passed to the following delegate methods:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

}
-(NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
        willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
       redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
}
```

try like this..

```
long long size = [response expectedContentLength];
```

Comment: It is deprecated as well.

Comment: – connection:needNewBodyStream
– connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:  required method Available in iOS 3.0 through iOS 4.3
– connection:didReceiveData:  required method Available in iOS 2.0 through iOS 4.3
– connection:didReceiveResponse:  required method Available in iOS 2.0 through iOS 4.3
– connection:willCacheResponse:  required method Available in iOS 2.0 through iOS 4.3
– connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:  required method Available in iOS 2.0 through iOS 4.3
– connectionDidFinishLoading: required method Available in iOS 2.0 through iOS 4.3

Answer (score 1):

For **Swift** use these steps,

Step 1: Use **NSURLConnectionDataDelegate**.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,NSURLConnectionDataDelegate {
```

Step 2: Create **request** for connection.

```
var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.twitter.com")!)

// Use **HEAD** request to get http header information.

request.HTTPMethod = "HEAD"
```

Step 3: Create **connection.**

```
var connection:NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self)!
```

Step 4: Use **delegate** method of **NSURLConnectionDataDelegate**

```
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse)
{
    var size = response.expectedContentLength
    println("size : \(size)")
}
```

Here is full code...

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,NSURLConnectionDataDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.twitter.com")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "HEAD"

    var connection:NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self)!

}

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse)
{
    var size = response.expectedContentLength
    println("size : \(size)")
}
}
```

Comment: is the size in bytes?

Comment: @RayKing , `So you can assume byte unit on most modern platform where a byte is 8 bits long.`  See here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/31389001/3411787

Answer (score 0):

try this will help . . . . .

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse
                                                                      *)response
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse * pHttpUrlResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;

    if ([response respondsToSelector:@selector(allHeaderFields)])
    {
        NSString * fileLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld",[pHttpUrlResponse expectedContentLength]];
    }    
}
```

happy coding :)

Comment: This is deprecated method that I listed in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Also using `URlSession` you can get the file size like this without downloading actual data:

```
func getPdfSize(for url: URL) {
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "HEAD"

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { [weak self] (_, response, _) in
        if let response = response {
            let size = response.expectedContentLength
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.fileSizeLabel.text = ByteCountFormatter.string(fromByteCount: size, countStyle: .file)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Notice also you can use the native iOS `ByteCountFormatter` to format the byte count into a readable string.

Code in Swift 5

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:URL error:&attributesError];
NSNumber *fileSizeNumber = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
long long fileSize = [fileSizeNumber longLongValue];
```

:)

Comment: This is for the already downloaded file, doesn't work for file on web.

Comment: Ok... For that i think you have to use ftp.