# What is the unit of the value returned by "expectedContentLength"

Tags: objective-c, nsurl

I am trying to set a data limit when doing connections.I am using the following function to get the size of the `NSURLResponse`.

```
   NSURLResponse *response;
  long long size = [response expectedContentLength];
```

I get the size as :`15219`

Is it  in bytes or bits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expectedContentLength` is set when the server provides it, such as by a `Content-Length` response header.

`Content-Length` is [defined](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) by:

> The Content-Length entity-header field indicates the size of the
>   entity-body, in decimal number of OCTETs, sent to the recipient or, in
>   the case of the HEAD method, the size of the entity-body that would
>   have been sent had the request been a GET.

So you can assume byte unit on most modern platform where a byte is 8 bits long.