# iOS - Setting total max size limit for downloads with AVAssetDownloadURLSession

Tags: ios, swift, offline-caching, avassetdownloadtask, avassetdownloadurlsession

I am creating an app to download audio tracks and videos with AVAssetDownloadURLSession and AVAssetDownloadTask. What I would love to do is set a threshold for downloads.

Say, the threshold is 5GB then total downloads would never exceed 5GB.

I went through the WWDC videos and said API documentation but was unable to find anything as such which will allow me to set a certain limit.

It would be great if any of you genius minds can point me to if the above scenario is possible with Apple APIs or I'll have to write my own implementation.

Comment: "I went through the WWDC videos and said API documentation"  Que!?  You mean, you've read it?

Comment: Yea, I could not notice anything that can help.

Comment: I don't think you can do that.  But see the doc for `URLSession` and `URLSessionConfiguration`.

Comment: Get a file size in reference to the following topic.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31736404/ios-get-file-size-before-downloading/48051898

Answer (score 0):

You could take a rough guess by multiplying the variant bitrate by the duration of AVAsset