# Get file size from a URL in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I'm developing an iOS application and I need your help to get size of files hosted on a remote web server.

When my app starts for the first time, it downloads different files in the user's DocumentDirectory folder, to do that I use URLSession and it works fine.

My problem is that at each startup my app downloads again all files. I'd like to compare the remote file size with the one located on the user's device to know if I have to download it or skipping it.

I did that for Android and it was very simple, our web server is compatible to get file size but for iOS I'm unable to find a solution on internet :(

I'm using Swift3.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28168551/4420355

Comment: Not really answering your question, but looking at the file size to check whether the file is up-to-date is not really best practice. You can try hashing the files and comparing the hash codes to determine if you need to download it again or not.

Answer (score -5):

let imageData =  NSData(contentsOfURL: URL!, options: NSDataReadingOptions())

NSLog(@"Data length: %u MB",(imageData.length/1024/1024));

Comment: This only works for images no?

Comment: It will work any file type.

Comment: This is a really bad solution because it downloads the whole file, and does it synchronously. In the linked answers there's solution to download only the headers from the server for getting the file attributes.