# Please, how to include a mechanism to disclose the download size of the additional resources needed to continue using my app, xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, applet

### My ios app was rejected by apple, and they asked me to do the following to resolve the problem. Can someone please help me fix this. I'm using xcode 9.3, but I'm not too much familiar with xcode.

### To resolve this issue, please revise your app to **include a mechanism to disclose the download size of the additional resources needed to continue using your app**. Additionally, be sure to **include a prompt to allow users to choose whether or not to start the download of the additional resources**.

Comment: do you have any additional data to download in your app ? if yes, you should show popup to the user informing the additional data download size and ask permission from user.

Comment: yes viveKDas, but how to add that kind of popup to my app with xcode?

Comment: When you download the additional data, don't download automatically, Show an alert to the user with message about the data and size you are going to download, if user select 'yes' button download the data else not. I think you know how to show Alert popup in iOS !

Comment: Yes viveKDas, that's exactly I need to do. The issue is that I'm not very family with xcode, can you please help guide me trough this? There are different audio files to download by clicking a play button located in different areas of the application, audio files have different size, the alert  must calculate automatically the size of each file and show it the user

Comment: On clicking the play button are you displaying any message to the user to indicate that the audio file is downloading ?

Comment: Yes, but the message doesn't show the download size

Comment: So if you are downloading the audio first and then playing you should show popup message to the user on clicking play button that - [do you want to download the audio file size 34 MB ? ](some message like this) with Yes and No button. If user click Yes start download the file and play else not.

Comment: Yes, how to add that kind of alert?

Comment: Check UIAlertController to show alert popup.
Link: https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/how-to-use-uialertcontroller-in-swift-70143d7fbede

Comment: Thanks viveKDas, I have seen it, but it is not well detailed for someone like me, lol.

Comment: how you developed the iOS app ? if you don't know about UIAlertController and alerts ?

Comment: The issue is not only the alert, but how to determine automatically the size of the to download, there up to 8000 to download

Comment: you can know the file size using the file URL before downloading 
Check these links: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43797281/swift-get-file-size-from-url
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43797281/swift-get-file-size-from-url?rq=1