# How to get file name and file size from UIDocumentPickerViewController in iOS 14?

Tags: ios, swift, uidocument, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I have to create feature for upload some document in pdf type and have to show name and file size with file that I selected from `UIDocumentPickerViewController 's delegate` before upload it.

How can I get its name and file size ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `UIDocumentPickerDelegate`, you have will end up implementing `documentPicker(_:didPickDocumentsAt:)`, which will give you an array of `URL`s. You can get the name of a file using `url.lastPathComponent`.

Regarding the file size, once you have the same `URL` from above, you can query the file size (may solutions listed here: [Swift - Get file size from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43797281/swift-get-file-size-from-url)):

```
do {
  let attribute = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: url.path)
  if let size = attribute[FileAttributeKey.size] as? NSNumber {
    let sizeInMB = size.doubleValue / 1000000.0
  }
} catch {
  print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: Oh! awesome, Thank you for your help @jnpdx. Can I ask more one question? for UIDocumentViewController, I have request any permission or open any capability ?

Comment: @NawinP. I'm pretty sure, no.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, probably is better to just count the content size. Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “....” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."

Comment: @CristiBăluță sounds like in your case you have to access it via a security scoped resource.

Comment: @jnpdx I thought that is for macos and you need to choose the file with NSOpenPanel. If I pass the url to open it with UIDocument works just fine though, so I found the size from the count of the data.

Comment: You are mistaken — it’s not just for macOS.