# Reading the mp3 file size and its length given NOTHING BUT a url?

Tags: html, ios, rss

I'm trying to create my own podcast iOS app.

First, I got a sample podcast rss feed from iTunes and try to parse it. And, I can't find the direct link to the mp3 file in the rss feed.

In each item, there is only a single link, let's say "http://allearsenglish.libsyn.com/aee-785-efficient-or-effective-how-to-use-both-words-in-english"

In order to provide the direct link to the mp3 file in the iOS app, I think I need to somehow get the source code of that website and find the mp3 file link.

My question is

1 Is there any iOS framework that allows me to parse a html file given a url?

2 How do you know the audio file size and its length given NOTHING BUT a url link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers:

1. Yes. There are many HTML parsers in both Objective-C and Swift. List with most of them: https://github.com/vsouza/awesome-ios#xml--html. Sorted by "Most stars":

   - https://github.com/topfunky/hpple (ObjC)
   - https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna (Swift)
   - https://github.com/honghaoz/Ji (Swift)
   - https://github.com/cezheng/Fuzi (Swift)
2. **Without downloading the file**: You can only get the file size (using a HEAD request, if the server supports it. [Answer with more details available here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19317092/2124535)) but not the track length.

If you are indeed going to create a podcast app, consider having a backend with all the necessary metadata.

iTunes Podcast's RSS feeds have all the details you are looking for. Live sample (extracted using http://itunes.so-nik.com/):

```
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>The Morning Stream</title>
        <link>http://frogpants.com/morningstream</link>
        <description>
            The Morning Stream, Mon thru Thurs, every morning, with Scott Johnson and the Frogpants Network. News, culture, politices and talk each and every day!
        </description>
        <generator>
            Feeder 2.5.12(2294); Mac OS X Version 10.12.5 (Build 16F73) http://reinventedsoftware.com/feeder/
        </generator>
        <docs>http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/tech/rss</docs>
        <language>en</language>
        <pubDate>Thu, 10 Aug 2017 17:16:58 -0600</pubDate>
        <lastBuildDate>Thu, 10 Aug 2017 17:16:58 -0600</lastBuildDate>
        <itunes:author>Scott Johnson</itunes:author>
        <itunes:image href="http://feeds.frogpants.com/morningstream_cover.jpg"/>
        <itunes:explicit>no</itunes:explicit>
        <itunes:owner>
            <itunes:name>Scott Johnson</itunes:name>
            <itunes:email>myextralife@gmail.com</itunes:email>
        </itunes:owner>
        <itunes:new-feed-url>http://feeds.frogpants.com/morningstream_feed.xml</itunes:new-feed-url>
        <itunes:block>no</itunes:block>
        <itunes:category text="Comedy"/>
        <itunes:category text="News & Politics"/>
        <item>
            <title>TMS PM 1318: Don't Blink</title>
            <link>
                http://feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mp3
            </link>
            <description>
                <![CDATA[
                    Lasered and feelin fine! Warmart is sorry about that. You look like big foot! That truck smells good. Even porn news. Dan Dan the Table Top Man! Your Twitter questions and more on this episode of TMSPM.
                ]]>
            </description>
            <pubDate>Thu, 10 Aug 2017 17:16:54 -0600</pubDate>
            <enclosure url="http://feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mp3" length="72444555" type="audio/mpeg"/>
            <guid isPermaLink="false">1CF58DA3-57BB-437A-BD00-229CA2CD29E6</guid>
            <itunes:author>Scott Johnson</itunes:author>
            <itunes:subtitle>
                Lasered and feelin fine! Warmart is sorry about that. You look like big foot! That truck smells good. Even porn news. Dan Dan the Table Top Man! Your Twitter questions and more on this episode of TMSPM.
            </itunes:subtitle>
            <itunes:summary>
                <![CDATA[
                    Lasered and feelin fine! Warmart is sorry about that. You look like big foot! That truck smells good. Even porn news. Dan Dan the Table Top Man! Your Twitter questions and more on this episode of TMSPM.
                ]]>
            </itunes:summary>
            <itunes:explicit>no</itunes:explicit>
            <itunes:duration>1:15:00</itunes:duration>
        </item>
        ...
```

As you can see, each item has a `duration`, `link` (to mp3 file) and `length`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @nathan, pls is there a way i can go about getting Life & Love from this `<itunes:category text="Life &amp; Love"/>`

I am using this library pls https://github.com/gcharita/XMLMapper