# iOS 10 get file size before download

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios10, nsmutableurlrequest

I need to get file size from url to decide whether i will download it or not. I tried it with `NSMutableURLRequest` but in the delegate, it returns -1 always. And the `NSMutableURLRequest` method is deprecated now. I added all the delegate (`NSURLConnectionDelegate`,`NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate`,`NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`) in `.h file` but it does not work. My code is :

```
NSMutableURLRequest * req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://download.quranicaudio.com/quran/abdullaah_3awwaad_al-juhaynee/001.mp3"]];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"Head"];
NSURLConnection * con = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req
                                                        delegate:self];
[con start];
[con release];


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{

NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse (%lld) ", response.expectedContentLength);

}
```

Already tried with : [How to find size of a file before downloading it in iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315533/how-to-find-size-of-a-file-before-downloading-it-in-ios-7)

Any solution for iOS 10+ ?

Comment: Why are you releasing the `con` object while you have just started the download?

Comment: @Torongo, Thanks for your look, but i already have commented the line. Not working anymore. The response is (-1)

Comment: did you set `NSAppTransportSecurity ` key in your info.plist?

Comment: The NSAppTransportSecurity is Yes already.

Comment: i just ran your code commented out the line `[con release]` and it gives me `710784` for `response.expectedContentLength`

Comment: Yes, you are right. The problem is in my real URL. The URL i use here is working but it's not my real URL. Thank you so much. :) @Torongo

Answer (score 0):

If you run the code after commenting `[con release]` it gives the exact size of your file.

Comment: Solved it already from comments. The problem is with my real URL. This URL is working.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `NSURLConnection`, instead use `NSURLSession` along with the `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` in your case. You can get the downloading file length by using property '`countOfBytesExpectedToReceive`' of `NSURLSessionTask` which is the super class of `NSURLSessionDownloadTask`. There are various beautiful libraries available for networking. You can use `AFNetworking` for example. Or you can write your own code. Here are some links may be useful to you:

- http://sweettutos.com/2014/09/16/how-you-would-use-nsurlsession-to-download-files/
- https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/stevez/archive/2014/05/21/ios-objective-c-downloading-data-using-nsurlsession.aspx

PS: You can handle your requirements at a more granular level by using  `NSURLSessionDelegate` methods for download task.

Comment: Solved it already from comments. The problem is with my real URL. This URL is working.